# How to select selected month data

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, forms

I have a HTML form inside which i have a Date-picker which is only for `month` and `Year`, so user is selecting month and year then submitting the form so at my server end i.e `Java Servlet` i am getting that value by `request.getParameter`
and it is giving `08/2018` 08 is the month and 2018 is year

so in my server end i have to write a query which can give me the data of the month-year which is selected

query i am thinking of is something like this

`select cashier from tableName where billdate=''`

so what value should i give to bill date so that it gives me data for the selected month like currently i have month as 08 and year as 2018

**Note:-** i am using MySql5.5

[image: This is my Database image]

**EDIT**

As i can use this query also :- `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE YEAR(billdate) = 2018 AND MONTH(billdate) = 8`

but the issue is i am getting date as `08/2019` how can i split it into two variables

Comment: *how can i split* - yes `String::split`

Comment: @ScaryWombat can you give me an example i didn't get your point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting date as `08/2019`. Then to split it into month and year, you can use String function split(). For example,

```
String monthYear = "08/2019";
String[] arr = monthYear.split("/");
String month = arr[0]; //08
String year = arr[1];  //2019
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use string.split:

```
String date = "08/2019";
String[] components = date.split("/");
String month = components[0];
String year = components[1];
```

If you have the day as well, you could parse a LocalDate from it:

```
String fullDate = "01/08/2019";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/uuuu");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(fullDate, formatter);
localDate.getYear();
localDate.getMonth();
```